# Does kendo angular provides heat map chart?

Tags: kendo-ui, angular8, kendo-angular-ui

Does **kendo** provide any way to implement heat map chart similar to highcharts heat map chart?( [Highcharts heatmap demo example](https://www.highcharts.com/demo/heatmap))

Comment: Take a look over here with all charts possible for Kendo Angular: [Kendo Angular Charts Overview](https://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/components/charts/)

Answer (score 1):

I just found this [`heatmap.component.ts`](https://github.com/telerik/kendo-angular/blob/7ffd0db370168e09909d7904d4133eaf0eac9708/examples-standalone/finance-portfolio/src/app/components/heatmap/heatmap.component.ts) in their [Angular GitHub project](https://github.com/telerik/kendo-angular).  So, yes, it can be done with custom code.

Comment: Thank you @xinthose for sharing useful information. I will go through it.